# Do all people getting Coronavirus need to be hospitalized for special care or it's just done to avoid spreading the disease?

Tags: covid-19

With the flu, it's estimated that 1 billion people gets the disease per year. Obviously, 1 billion people can't be hospitalized. What could happen if the health system of a country collapses (not enough beds/professionals to attend all people) and only the serious/critical cases can be hospitalized. Do all people getting Coronavirus need to be hospitalized for special care or it's just done to avoid spreading the disease?

Answer (score -1):

[image]

Covid-19 infection has a low mortality rate in people under the age of 50. They are recoverable without special treatment. Because of the risks you mentioned, low-risk patients may be advised to avoid hospitalization.

Comment: Mortality is not the same as morbidity. 50% of ICU beds in France are being filled with people in their 40s who would not survive without hospital level care.